# How to set table td ids using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am working on a table and I need to set the generated row(s) tds id. But I don't know how. Below is the html with two td. I need to set there ids via javascript function.

Here the is the html:

```
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td onclick="myFunction()">Row1 cell1</td>
    <td>Row1 cell2</td>
  </tr>  
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
function myFunction() {
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var row = table.insertRow(0);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    cell1.innerHTML = "NEW CELL1";
    cell2.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dxkf4fe2/1/ - what ids do you want to set

Comment: @Arun, all the <td> generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the id property

```js
var rowCount = 0;
function myFunction() {
  var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  var row = table.insertRow(0);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  cell1.id = 'row' + ++rowCount + '-cell1'
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  cell2.id = 'row' + rowCount + '-cell2'
  cell1.innerHTML = "NEW CELL1";
  cell2.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td onclick="myFunction()">Row1 cell1</td>
    <td>Row1 cell2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks. I have some slight problem when generating the row. It is generated or being added above the initial row. I think I need to add it below the initial.

Answer (score 0):

```
cell1.setAttribute("id", "id_1");
cell2.setAttribute("id", "id_2");
```

Answer (score 0):

`setAttribute("id","idname");`
this sets id name of any element dynamically